# Cannot connect laptop to monitor using HDMI

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, projector

I'm trying to connect my Dell Latitude laptop to my monitor using an HDMI connection from both ends. I plugged in the cable, but my monitor is showing no signal.

I tried to send output to the projector (it can be done with the Fn+F8 shortcut) and it does nothing except resize my screen to square size.

Any idea what is missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: And you have switched the input on the TV to the appropriate HDMI port?

Comment: try a different hdmi cable, and make sure the resolution of the projector can handle that specific output you have for the hdmi port.

Comment: Check your drivers. You often need to have the real card drivers(not generic ones) to use HDMI. I'm assuming you are on Windows 7 or 8, you may want to tag your OS and put what type of model system you have.